# Resize data drive in EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, partition

Ubuntu 10, with 2 drives: root (8 gb), and data (sdf, 150 gb).

I created a snapshot, and then created a drive from the snapshot, sizing it to 300 gb.

I then shutdown the instance, removed the 150 drive, and attached 300 one.

Sever booted up fine, and all data is there, but sdf is still showing up as 150 gb.

I know how to resize a partition on a machine I have physical access to, but how would I do this safely in EC2?

Comment: If you know how to do it, you know how to do it. If you created the snapshot, and then created the new volume with the new size, the only thing left is extend the partition inside the OS. Do it as you normally would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is it:
`sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`

Full instructions:
http://alestic.com/2010/02/ec2-resize-running-ebs-root

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below mentioned steps:

First :

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/xvdi1
```

Then resize:

```
sudo resize2fs  /dev/xvdi1
```